# Array Manipulation from SQL results

Tags: php

is it possible to turn this data (retrieved from sql database) into this data

```
[{
"DATE": "2016-02-08",
"STORE": "1",
"SALES": "34"
}, {
"DATE": "2016-02-08",
"STORE": "2",
"SALES": "11"
}, {
"DATE": "2016-02-08",
"STORE": "3",
"SALES": "19"
}]
```

into this

```
[{
"DATE": "2016-02-08",
"STORE1": "34",
"STORE2": "11",
"STORE3":"19"
}]
```

either through the sql select or array manipulation?

`EDIT`

to extend this question further if the array contained multiple days how would i create a multidimensional array like below

```
Array (
[0] => array (
    "DATE": "2016-02-08",
    "STORE1": "34",
    "STORE2": "11",
    "STORE3":"19"
    )
[1] => array (
    "DATE": "2016-02-08",
    "STORE1": "34",
    "STORE2": "11",
    "STORE3":"19"
)
)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's possible either through sql depending on your structure or by just using plain PHP afterwards.

Comment: How is it possible through sql @purpleninja ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array manipulation is simple:

```
$final = [];
foreach($results AS $result) {
    $final['DATE'] = $result['DATE'];
    $final['STORE' . $result['STORE']] = $result['SALES'];
}
```

The `$final` array will have what you want.

Working example: https://3v4l.org/XqWUT

**Edit**

If you have different dates and need the `$final` array to be multi-dimensional, here's a new working example link: https://3v4l.org/9ctpU

Comment: Instead of just one `$final` create a separate variable for each day, basically. Update your question with details if you want more info.